# How can a superclass variable hold data member values that only exist in subclass?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to understand how a variable of type superclass can store values in data members that only exist in the subclass.

For example in Java, lets say class `Child` extends `Parent`.  `Child` has a data member `childMember` (let's assume it's an `int`).

This is legal in Java:

`Parent parentObject = new Child();
((Child)parentObject).childMember = 5;`

But how can the `parentObject` store a value for `childMember` since it is of type `Parent` and `Parent` doesn't have the `childMember`?  I know it is being cast to set the value, but how does it even have the data member to be able to store it since it isn't a child object?

Comment: _"since it isn't a child object?"_ It is because it is `new Child()`. It's not about the declaration type but the actual instance type.

Comment: It is a child object. You wrote `new Child()`.

Comment: So even though it was declared as a type Parent, it becomes a Child when it is assigned as new Child()?  If so, then why must I cast it to set childMember?

Comment: No.  variable `parentObject` can hold a reference to *any* `Parent`.  Since class `Child` extends `Parent`, instance of `Child` are also `Parent`s, and `parentObject` can hold a reference to one of these.  Nothing changes in the course of the assignment.  But you need the cast when you assign because `parentObject` could also, in principle, hold a reference to a `Parent` that is *not* a `Child`: you are asserting that when that expression is evaluated, it will actually hold a reference to a `Child`.

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
Parent parentObject = new Child(); 
((Child)parentObject).childMember = 5;
```

The `parentObject` object's actual/runtime class is `Child`, and that explains why all works.

> But how can the parentObject store a value for childMember since it is of type Parent and parent doesn't have the childMember?

This question is more applicable to this code:

```
Parent parentObject = new Parent(); 
((Child)parentObject).childMember = 5;
```

In this case, however, the cast `((Child)parentObject)` will not work, and Java will raise a `ClassCastException` at runtime, as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the *reference* is of type `Parent`, the object *it points* to is of type `Child`, thus your entire logic works as detailed in the other answer.

But this is a pretty trivial example, let's do a funner one:

```
static class Parent {
    public int x = 5;
}

static class Child extends Parent {
    public int x = 3;
}
```

How many `x`'s does `Child` have? Well...

```
Arrays.stream(Child.class.getFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println); // x AND x again
```

How do you then access each of them?

```
Child c = new Child();
System.out.println(c.x); // 3

Parent p = c;
System.out.println(p.x); // 5
```

Comment: This makes an important remark... and highlights the danger of hiding fields.

Comment: @ernest_k well if we are here (on hiding part), does it make sense to declare static methods `final`?

Comment: I'd have wanted to say it doesn't make sense. But I had never thought of it. Typing that in the IDE causes an error (cannot "override" static final method)

Comment: Maybe java is trying to protect those who reference static methods using instances (of parent or child classes)... This is very sad.

Comment: @ernest_k you are touching so many good subjects here btw :) about your last comment : no - this has always been possible `someInstance.staticMethod` (but seen as a design error), and fixed with method references, you can't do `someInstance::someStaticMethod`

Comment: of course, it's always been possible. My point was to rationalize **why** java prevents hiding a static final method of a superclass. Because static methods aren't overridden anyway, I don't see why the `final` keyword is enforced (hence, I thought, it's to add a thin layer of protection for those who call static methods on instances)

Comment: @ernest_k about that error message... it has bugged me for quite some time. Think about it: the compiler says cannot override... static methods are inherited, but not overridable, so this error message makes little sense to begin with. then since such a method already exists in child class (and two methods final and non-final do not count as overloads) it simply cant inherit it OR say something about hiding...

Comment: @ernest_k last comment and I'm leaving you alone (thx for the fun chat!) when you run this against sonar - it says remove final as it makes no sense, but it does makes sense, well to me, as it prevents hiding

Comment: So we're saying the same thing... except that you started pondering over it long before it occurred to me... thanks!